# Cannot interact with directory, how to remove it

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a directory with a lot of files that I want to remove but I cannot interact with it.

The size of the folder is 29M. `rm -rf` ran overnight without it seems doing anything.

`find . -type f -print | head -n 1` doesn't print anything, I can see in htop that it doesn't actually run but is in state `D`. Same with `find . -type f -delete`.

Could it be corrupted or something like that? How can I check for that and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `D` state means `uninterruptible` - see [here](https://peteris.rocks/blog/htop/#d-uninterruptible-sleep-usually-io) for a nice description. You may be forced to restart your server unless someone can chip in with a better solution to interrupt the uninterruptible!

My original guess was that the file is probably as 'in use' by an open process. Try using `lsof` to find the process and restart it/end it if possible. Maybe killing that process will break the lock?